# Choosing a security related diploma thesis topic - encrypted HW pentesting

Tags: penetration-test, hardware

I am currently studying an IT-security masters course and want to choose an interesting diploma thesis topic.

A possible supervisor of my thesis suggested pentesting self-encrypting USB/HDD/etc., however he did not suggest a specific form. Some of his suggestions were :

- Pentesting an older, vulnerable device
- Finding and (if successful in obtaining one) pentesting an intentionally vulnerable device
- Pentesting a self-made device, intentionally vulnerable device
- A summary of currently available solutions/intentionally vulnerable devices (but without a practical part)

I wasn't particularly interested in the last two, because I have no experience in creating HW (not even with some Arduino or things like that) and because I would like to have some hands-on experience while writing my diploma thesis.

And since I have no prior experience in the area of HW pentesting, could you please tell me, which oneof those topics could be the best for a diploma thesis and why should I pick it - based on your experience ?

Thank you very much

Comment: [Buy one](https://www.kingston.com/en/usb/encrypted_security) (I am not recommending the manufacturer or saying their devices are susceptible) hook up a [jtag device](https://www.xjtag.com/about-jtag/what-is-jtag/) and get the key once it has been derived.

Comment: Welcome. This question is pretty open-ended. "Suggest more interesting topics" does not fit the StackExchange Q&A format. "Pros and cons of the topics" is also open-ended (difficult to have a single acceptable answer). If you can narrow your question, we can have a better go at it.

Comment: Sorry, but now the question is purely opinion-based and still not a good fit. Please take a look at the FAQ.

Comment: @schroeder I have edited the last paragraph, hope it narrowed it down.

Comment: @schroeder I have made yet another edit - I am sorry if it still is not good enough, however the nature of this question is subjective. I have tried to follow the "subejctive question guideline" in FAQ (experience-based answers explaining why), but I am afraid I cannot narrow it down any more. In case it's not fit for SO, could you please at least point me to where such question might be answered ? Thank you very much

Comment: You can have a look at [Academia.se], your question will probably still be off-topic there in its current form, but you could gather some info on approaches to choosing thesis topics.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is requesting career/academic advice